# Is reading mysql documentation a good way to learn mariadb concepts?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I want to learn mariadb. But it's documentation is not good for beginners. For example they don't even explain what is a storage engine. So the documentation is for users who already know the basics.

Mysql has better documentation. So i wondered if i could study it to learn mariadb concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Since MariaDB is actually (at some point) based on MySQL, I believe it is a reasonable way to learn concepts.

In any way, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-features/ is also a good reference. There you have explanations to storage engines as well.